# Vibrator doesnt not always trigger

Tags: java, android

I'm using Vibrator class to make the android device vribrate each time a button is pressed. but sometimes after 10 or 40 times in a row it stops, and sometimes it works again. that's pretty random. so what's wrong, my code? the way to use it ? 
btw that's how I use it:

```
private Vibrator v;

v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

...

```
 up.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        if (map[posy-1][posx] == 1) {
                            v.vibrate(30);
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Before someone ask to check my condition, it always works. I used Log to be sure. and it prints everytimes...